# Mainactivity.java or Katlin folder file is not present in my flutter project

Tags: flutter, dart

[here is image for my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8qvM.png)  When I run my flutter project on my phone it popup and immediately closes. I Expect that this is Happened because of missing Maingactivit.java or kottlin if this is the case how I fix it

```
Here is Error I Face
        Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.likecse_astu.nethouese.MainActivity
    E/AndroidRuntime(14139):        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    E/AndroidRuntime(14139):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
    E/AndroidRuntime(14139):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
    E/AndroidRuntime(14139):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
    E/AndroidRuntime(14139):        ... 12 more
    E/AndroidRuntime(14139):    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available

Logcat Error code
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.likecse_astu.nethouese.MainActivity
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
    at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
            ... 12 more
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply create the class file MainActivity.java with the Java code.

```
public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);
   }
}
```

Or run one of these commands: `flutter create .` or `flutter create -a java .`